# Is my Windows upgrade installation really running?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1607

My **Software Center** app in Windows 10 Enterprise is permanently showing that a Windows upgrade is installing but the status remains there after 3 days even after a few manual computer restarts and even after restarting of **Windows Update** and **SMS Agent Host** services (with deletion of **C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore** directory in between).

- The **Installing...** state (see screenshot below) is visible immediately after restart.
- The **Cancel** button is disabled all the time.
- Manual restart procedure never displays things like *Updating your computer*.

How can I stop and restart this stuck installation or at least check whether the installer is doing something?

[image]

[I moved comments to chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67840/discussion-between-miroxlav-and-appleoddity)

Comment: Have you tried contacting your IT department? Have you tried this through normal Windows updates?

Comment: Windows enterprise is only available to businesses. Software Center is used in enterprises as part of SCCM to allow non-admin users to install software within a Windows domain. Therefore, for you to be using Software Center you are part of an organization and this is a managed machine. The process of installing the update is controlled by your IT department and should be resolved there. This is not how a typical user would install a Windows update. Software Center doesn’t even exist on a home PC.

Comment: Thus the reason why I asked “Have you tried this through normal Windows Updates?” We don’t have any insight in to the policies of your organization or how SCCM has been configured. All I can suggest is that your organization broke something. Download and install Windows 10 anniversary update the way users do - through Windows Update or the media creation tool.

Answer (score 0):

It looks it was needed to

1. Enter **Update & Security** settings window
2. Check **Check online for updates from Microsoft Update**
3. Press **Check for updates**
   (now the above check box gets unchecked again, but this is fine)

Multiple rounds of steps **2** and **3** got the updates moving.

Now this is the progress:

[image]

I am receiving version 1703 instead of previously planned 1607 but hopefully it will be OK. (Update: It was OK.)

Comment: last Win10 version is 1709 not 1703

Comment: @magicandre1981 – thanks, I removed words "the latest".